# grouping a matrix in C#

Tags: c#, grouping

I have a matrix (or we can call it a datatable) with 3 columns and x rows.
I should create groups according to the values of column1 and column2.
(if the value of column1 and column 2 in different rows are the same, then these rows must be in the same group).
How can I do it in C#?

Comment: A matrix is not a data-table (strictly speaking, a _relation_). Anyway, you can use Linq via `DataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().GroupBy( r => new { Col1 = r["Column1"], Col2 = r["Column2"] } )``

Comment: It really depends on the data types you are using. Do you have an actual `DataTable`? A `Matrix<T>`? A `object[,]` ? the answer will depend on the specifics, so an example would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you have a `DataTable`

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
```

And you want to *query* it; you can do it with a help of *Linq*, something like this:

```
var result = table
  .Rows
  .OfType<DataRow>()
  .GroupBy(row => (row[0], row[1]), row => row[2]);
```

Here we group by `0`th and `1`st columns while using `2`nd column in the grouping.